# How do you change the selected radio button which is part of a template-driven form in the change event of the radio button group?

Tags: angular, typescript, events, angular-material, radio-button

I am using Angular Material, the radiobutton group, have two radio buttons in a group, one is "Accept", the other "Reject", having values "A" and "R".
I am throwing up a confirmation dialog in response to a user clicking on the "Reject" radio button, and need to change the selected radio button to "Accept" (A) if the user specifies "Cancel" in the confirm.

My code is in the change event of the radiobuttongroup.

The radio button group is bound to a variable "statusCode" using [(ngModel)], and is part of a template-driven form.

```
onRadioChange($event: MatRadioChange) {
    if ($event.value === 'R' && this.userNeedsToChange) {
       let result = confirm('Are you sure you want to reject? You cannot reverse this decision');
       if (!result) {
           this.statusCode = 'A';
       }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, ng-hobby. I like your solutions.
I also just got it to work by adding the statement 
$event.source.checked = false;
before this.statusCode = 'A'

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways for achieving your purpose generally. Using **Reactive Forms** or **Template-driven Forms** as you said.

For changing the value in the template-driven you have to use the **LocalReference** & @ViewChild() decorator in your component like the following example:

In HTML:

```
<mat-radio-group>
  <mat-radio-button value="1" #email>Email</mat-radio-button>  
  <mat-radio-button value="2">Mobile</mat-radio-button>    
</mat-radio-group>
<br/>
```

There is a local reference like "#email" and in the component we can use it like this:

```
import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-reactive',
  templateUrl: './reactive-form.component.html'
})
export class TemplateFormComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor() {} 

  @ViewChild('email') 
  emailRB: MatRadioButton;


  RadioChanged( event ) {
    let result = confirm('Are you sure you want to reject? You cannot reverse this decision');
    if (!result) {
           this.emailRB.focus();
     }
  }
```

So, this code can help selecting the desired radio button.

For more example see the following link:

https://www.concretepage.com/angular-material/angular-material-radio-button

But the better way is using the Reactive Forms like this:

```
<form class="radio-btn-container" [formGroup]="acceptanceFG">
  <label class="radio-main-lable">Acceptance: </label>
  <mat-radio-group formControlName="acceptance">
    <mat-radio-button value="A">
       <span class="radio-option-lable">Accept</span>
    </mat-radio-button>
    <mat-radio-button value="R">
       <span class="radio-option-lable">Reject</span>
    </mat-radio-button>
  </mat-radio-group>
</form>
```

And on the component:

```
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup, Validators, FormControl } from '@angular/forms';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-reactive',
  templateUrl: './reactive-form.component.html'
})
export class ReactiveFormComponent implements OnInit {

acceptanceFG: FormGroup;

constructor(private _formBuilder: FormBuilder ){}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.acceptanceFG= this._formBuilder.group({
       acceptance: new FormControl( null, { validators: Validators.required   }),
    });
  }

    RadioChanged( event ) {
    let result = confirm('Are you sure you want to reject? You cannot reverse this decision');
    if (!result) {
       this.acceptanceFG.patchValue( { acceptance: 'R' } );
     }
  }
}
```

Hope this was an enough explanation and it helps ! ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
HTML
    <mat-radio-button
    #myradio
    (change)="select(element)">
    </mat-radio-button>

TS
@ViewChild('myradio')
  myradio: MatRadioButton;


this.myradio.checked = false; //unchecked
```